# How can I track system call in win32 API program with debugger(VS 2013)?

Tags: c, winapi

Well, I wrote a code for File I/O with Win32 API.
(I'm using Visual studio 2013)

It just gets two file name(one for source, one for destination) and duplicate one to another.

I used CreateFile, ReadFile, WriteFile.

It's functionally simple. It's not problem. But..

I wanna SEE the system call in these function being called in debugger.

How can I do this?

with Call stack? Disassembler?

Comment: Any specific reason on finding the system call?

Comment: Assignment for Operating System class :p

Comment: You can [Set a Function Breakpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/15d1wtaf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on *ntdll.dll!NtCreateFile*, *ntdll.dll!NtReadFile*, and *ntdll.dll!NtWriteFile*.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to be able to debug not only your own code but also the API itself.
There are different ways to do that.

At the simplest level, just use the debugger from VS2013. You won't be able to trace into kernel code, but all the user level code in the API. But of course as you will use a non debug version of Windows with no symbol table you will only see low-level machine code (*).

If you really want to go deeper, you will have to use the [Debugging Tools for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As you say you want to debug system calls, my advice would be to use the Windows Driver Kit, the Windows Symbols, and if you really go down to kernel mode the Windows Remote Debugging Client for Windows (all those tools are available from [Windows Dev Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/gg454513)).

All those tools integrate nicely in VisualStudio, but be prepared to hard low level work :-)

(*) You can also use the Microsof Symbol Server to access windows symbolic information - thanks to IInspectable for his comment. But I've never tested.

Comment: When [using the Microsoft Symbol Server to obtain debug symbol files](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311503), you don't need a debug version of Windows to see symbolic information. .pdb's contain all the information needed; executable code doesn't need to be instrumented to allow symbol lookup.